Listing categories through GraphQL doesn't work
When I try to retrieve a list of categories with the below GraphQL query, I only get one result instead of the expected 8.
All the configuration options for the categories are default.
Listing Categories
query Categories {
  categories(pageSize: 50) {
    items {
      name
      uid
    }
    total_count
  }
}

Result
{
  "data": {
    "categories": {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Osobní Automobil",
          "uid": "NQ=="
        }
      ],
      "total_count": 1
    }
  }
}

Expected Result
A list of all the defined categories.
My category tree


You are receiving this category as the parent (main) category for your store. You need to create a parent category or choose from the existing ones and move the necessary categories there that you would like to see in your store. After that, you need to set the Root Category in the store's settings:
Stores -> All Stores -> Store Name (Stores column) -> Root Category.


After you do this, you will still only see one main category with the query:
query Categories {
  categories(pageSize: 50) {
    items {
      name
      uid
    }
    total_count
  }
}

To retrieve subcategories, you need to add the children field with the necessary fields to the items object in your query, and so on.
For example:
query Categories {
  categories(pageSize: 50) {
    items {
      name
      uid
      children {
        name
        uid
        children {
          uid
          name
        }
      }
    }
    total_count
  }
}

